# Steps to print from wireless printer

Tags: wireless-networking, printing

Trying to get my parents' laptop (Lenovo X61) to send print commands to their HP Deskjet 6940 wireless printer.

Their laptop has wifi and the home WLAN is operational and works; printer is connected to it as well (because they have other laptops that can print to it).

When I go to print I dont see this printer as an option.

Do I need to install the drivers before I search for available printers on the network? What are the basic steps to setting this up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If their printer came with a CD, I'd start there.  The installer on the CD can generally detect the printer.